# Bing Ads API - Filter On Ad Delivery Status

Tags: bing-ads-api

I'm trying to do something which I believe should be a very basic function of the Bing Ads API, but I'm running into trouble. What I want to do is make a custom report showing all Bing ads that have been disapproved or are prohibited from being served for one reason or another. In the Bing Ads interface I can view this information without too much fuss as a filter in the 'Ads' tab.

[image: Bing Ads Interface - Filter on Disapproval Status]

I searched through the documentation, specifically focusing on [AdPerformanceReportFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/reporting-service/adperformancereportfilter?view=bingads-13) but the only segments I can filter on are:

- 'AccountStatus'
- 'AdDistribution'
- 'AdGroupStatus'
- 'AdStatus'
- 'AdType'
- 'CampaignStatus'
- 'DeviceType'
- 'Language'

I've thoroughly searched the Keyword, Campaign and Ad Group Report Filter objects as well to no avail. I wouldn't mind pulling all ads on the account and then filtering myself, except that even on the [AdPerformanceReportColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/reporting-service/adperformancereportcolumn?view=bingads-13), there are no attributes that relate to Ad Delivery or anything like what I can see in the interface.

Strangely, I found this Bing Ads Scripts (similar to Google Ads Scripts) [solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/scripts/solutions/get-disapproved-ads) which does exactly what I'm trying to do, except it only runs on the Bing platform and I cannot replicate it or run it from my app.

Is any one able to point out what I'm missing? I want to see all the disapproved ads on my accounts so that I can address them more quickly.

Thanks so much for reading and taking the time to consider my question.

Comment: Have you tried filtering by 'Rejected' ad status? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/reporting-service/adstatusreportfilter?view=bingads-13#rejected

Otherwise GetAdsByEditorialStatus results could be merged with your reports:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/campaign-management-service/getadsbyeditorialstatus?view=bingads-13

Does this help?

Comment: I can certainly filter by AdStatus. However I wasn't aware that serving status was the same property as approval status. Can you confirm that all disapproved ads will fall into the 'rejected' bucket? There seem to be a lot more filtering options available in the interface so it's hard to believe that the 'rejected' group encompasses them all.